# Stop scaling of the background image of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

EDIT 1:

The jar of MigLayout are:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/miglayout/miglayout-core/5.1-SNAPSHOT/miglayout-core-5.1-20170315.230019-713.jar

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/miglayout/miglayout-swing/5.1-SNAPSHOT/miglayout-swing-5.1-20170315.230038-713.jar

OP:

I have a JPanel as the "main screen" of a Java Swing application. It's not resizable. In this main screen I have buttons to direct the user to different functions/parts of the application, each of these functions in a different JPanel. I use CardLayout to organized these panels, put them in a `JPanel panelCentro`, and add this panel into the contentPane of the main screen.

In main frame:

```
panelCentro.setLayout(new CardLayout());
//getContentPane().setLayout(null);
getContentPane().add(panelCentro);
```

`panelCentro` has a background image. I overwrite the `paintComponent` method of this panel, to paint the image.

All works as expected only if I use `null` as the layout manager in the `panelCentro`. The problems lies in that the function panels should accept resizing.

When they are resized, the main screen container is resized, too, and if I use some layout manager to manager the `panelCentro`, the image resizes, too, because (I guess) the layout manager will call `repaint()`, thus, call `paintComponent()` to paint the background.

But, remember that the main screen is not resizable, and when I click the "back" button to return to the main screen, it returns to the original size, and the background image will show before the scaling is complete, thus, distorted.

Here you have an SSCCE to show somehow how the image is distorted. The image is shown below as example. Download it and rename it to "back.png", and move it to the `img` directory of the project. Maximize the windows, keep clicking the "Toggle" button, and the image will expand every time the panel is shown (you notice it seeing the button continuously moves downwards), and in about 10 times of clicking, it stops resizing.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class AutoResizingProblem extends JFrame {

    private static final Font ARIAL_PLAIN_15 = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15);
    private static final Font ARIAL_BOLD_14 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14); //FONT++
    private static final Font ARIAL_PLAIN_14 = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14); //font++
    private static final Font CONSOLAS_PLAIN_14 = new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 14); //FONT++
    private static final Font ARIAL_PLAIN_13 = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13);//font++

    private JPanel panel2;
    public AutoResizingProblem() {
        begin();
    }

    private void begin() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 5, fillx", "[]", "[]5[]"));

        final JPanel content = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(content, "cell 0 0, grow");

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 5 5 5 5", "[fill, grow]5[300!]", "[]10[]5[fill, grow]5[]5[]"));
        panel.setOpaque(false);
        panel.setVisible(true);


        final JLabel lblreconstruccinDelRegistro = new JLabel("<html>Reconstrucci\u00F3n del Registro de Env\u00EDos y Respuestas</html>");
        lblreconstruccinDelRegistro.setToolTipText("<html>Reconstrucci\u00F3n del Registro de Env\u00EDos y Respuestas</html>");
        lblreconstruccinDelRegistro.setOpaque(true);
        lblreconstruccinDelRegistro.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblreconstruccinDelRegistro.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblreconstruccinDelRegistro.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        lblreconstruccinDelRegistro.setFont(ARIAL_PLAIN_15);
        lblreconstruccinDelRegistro.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        lblreconstruccinDelRegistro.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
        lblreconstruccinDelRegistro.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Menu.background"));

        panel.add(lblreconstruccinDelRegistro, "cell 0 0, span 2, h 25!, grow");      

        JLabel lblSeguimiento = new JLabel("Seguimiento actual:");
        lblSeguimiento.setToolTipText("Seguimiento actual");
        lblSeguimiento.setFont(ARIAL_BOLD_14);
        panel.add(lblSeguimiento, "cell 0 1, split 3, h 25!");
        JRadioButton rbMantener = new JRadioButton();
        rbMantener.setText("Mantener");
        rbMantener.setFont(ARIAL_PLAIN_14);
        panel.add(rbMantener, ""); //add after the label of Seuigimiento, same cell.

        JRadioButton rbEliminar = new JRadioButton();
        rbEliminar.setText("Eliminar");
        rbEliminar.setFont(ARIAL_PLAIN_14);
        panel.add(rbEliminar, "grow");

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(rbMantener);
        group.add(rbEliminar);

        JButton btnIniciarRBD = new JButton("Iniciar Reconstrucci\u00F3n");
        btnIniciarRBD.setFont(ARIAL_PLAIN_14);
        panel.add(btnIniciarRBD, "cell 1 1, gapleft push, h 30!, gapright 5");

        JPanel panelListasPorProcesar = new JPanel();
        panelListasPorProcesar.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0 0 0 0, fillx, debug","[50%]5[50%]", "[25!]5[45%]5[45%]"));
        panelListasPorProcesar.setOpaque(false);
        panelListasPorProcesar.setBorder(null);
//              panelListasPorProcesar.setBounds(10, 100, 440, 270);
        panel.add(panelListasPorProcesar, "cell 0 2, grow");

     // Label "Número de ficheros por procesar"
        JLabel lblNmeroDeFicherosPorProcesar = new JLabel();
        lblNmeroDeFicherosPorProcesar.setFont(ARIAL_BOLD_14);

        panelListasPorProcesar.add(lblNmeroDeFicherosPorProcesar, "cell 0 0, grow, span 2");

        JLabel lblBuznDeEntrada = new JLabel();
        lblBuznDeEntrada.setFont(ARIAL_PLAIN_14);
        ;

        panelListasPorProcesar.add(lblBuznDeEntrada, "cell 0 1, split 2, flowy, h 25!, grow");

        final JList listaRB01 = new JList();
        listaRB01.setOpaque(true);
        listaRB01.setBorder(null);
        listaRB01.setFont(CONSOLAS_PLAIN_14);       
        JScrollPane spRB01 = new JScrollPane();

        spRB01.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        spRB01.setViewportView(listaRB01);

        panelListasPorProcesar.add(spRB01, "cell 0 1, grow");

        JLabel lblFicherosRnt = new JLabel();
        lblFicherosRnt.setFont(ARIAL_PLAIN_14);

        panelListasPorProcesar.add(lblFicherosRnt, "cell 1 1, flowy, split 2, h 25!, grow");


        JList listaRB02 = new JList();
        listaRB02.setOpaque(true);
        listaRB02.setBorder(null);
        listaRB02.setFont(CONSOLAS_PLAIN_14);
        JScrollPane spRB02 = new JScrollPane();

        spRB02.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        spRB02.setViewportView(listaRB02);

        panelListasPorProcesar.add(spRB02, "cell 1 1, grow");



        JLabel lblFicherosDcl = new JLabel();
        lblFicherosDcl.setFont(ARIAL_PLAIN_14);

        panelListasPorProcesar.add(lblFicherosDcl, "cell 0 2, split 2, flowy, h 25!, grow");
        // Lista "Ficheros DCL"
        JList listaRB03 = new JList();
        listaRB03.setOpaque(true);
        listaRB03.setFont(CONSOLAS_PLAIN_14);

        JScrollPane spRB03 = new JScrollPane();

        spRB03.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        spRB03.setViewportView(listaRB03);      

//              panelListasPorProcesar.add(spRB03);
        panelListasPorProcesar.add(spRB03, "cell 0 2, grow");


        JLabel lblFicherosRlc = new JLabel();
        lblFicherosRlc.setFont(ARIAL_PLAIN_14);

        panelListasPorProcesar.add(lblFicherosRlc, "cell 1 2, split 2, flowy, h 25!, grow");

        // Lista "Ficheros RLC"
        JList listaRB04 = new JList();
        listaRB04.setOpaque(true);
        listaRB04.setBorder(null);
        listaRB04.setFont(CONSOLAS_PLAIN_14);

        JScrollPane spRB04 = new JScrollPane();

        spRB04.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        spRB04.setViewportView(listaRB04);      

        panelListasPorProcesar.add(spRB04, "cell 1 2, grow");

        JLabel lblNmeroDeFicherosProcesados = new JLabel();
        lblNmeroDeFicherosProcesados.setFont(ARIAL_BOLD_14);

        panel.add(lblNmeroDeFicherosProcesados, "cell 1 2, grow, split 2, flowy, align left, h 25!");

        JList listaRBProcesados = new JList();
        listaRBProcesados.setOpaque(true);
        listaRBProcesados.setBorder(null);
        listaRBProcesados.setFont(CONSOLAS_PLAIN_14);

        JScrollPane spRBProcesados = new JScrollPane();
        spRBProcesados.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        spRBProcesados.getViewport().setOpaque(false);

        spRBProcesados.setViewportView(listaRBProcesados);



        panel.add(spRBProcesados, "cell 1 2, grow");


        JLabel lblAvance = new JLabel("A long bar");
        lblAvance.setFont(ARIAL_PLAIN_14);
        lblAvance.setForeground(Color.BLACK); 

        panel.add(lblAvance, "cell 0 3, span 2, grow");


        JButton button = new JButton("Toggle");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CardLayout cl = null;
                cl = (CardLayout)content.getLayout();
                if (panel.isVisible()) {
                    System.out.println("show panel2");
                    cl.show(content, "panel2");
                } else if (panel2.isVisible()) {
                    System.out.println("show panel1");
                    cl.show(content, "panel1");
                }
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(button, "cell 0 1, grow");


        content.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        content.add(panel, "panel1");

        panel2 = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                Dimension tamanio = getSize();
                ImageIcon imagenDeFondo = new ImageIcon("img/back.png");
                g.drawImage(imagenDeFondo.getImage(), 0, 0, tamanio.width, tamanio.height, null);
                setOpaque(false);
//              super.paintComponent(g);
            }

//            @Override
//            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
//                return new Dimension(600,400);
//            }
        };

        content.add(panel2, "panel2");
//        setContentPane(panel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                AutoResizingProblem frame = new AutoResizingProblem();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve, is:

1. When showing the functional panels, show them with background resizable.
2. When returning to the main screen, locate the frame in the middle, and immediately resize it to original unscaled size, or, don't show it when it's scaled properly.

What I do now, is with null layout with dirty manual work(listening to `componentResized()`. But it's against the doctrine of many here. Is there a way to do this with some layout manager? If it's not possible, I would say that absolute positioning is sometimes useful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code is not a SSCCE - MigLayout is missing - so I could not test it!

If you do not want the image scaled, use the drawImage method without size:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    ...
    g.drawImage(imagenDeFondo.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
    ...
```

*this answer is based mostly on the title of the question*

Comment: Sorry for forgetting providing the link to the jar. See edit.

Comment: thanks, but that is not the problem... I am able to find the JAR/link myself;I just cannot and do not want to install every JAR that appears on Stackoverflow. BUT the idea of a Short, Self Contained Correct Example is that it should be simple to copy and run it without having to install or download any additional stuff. Anyway you did better than lots I have seen here...